# How to pass order details from phone gap app to opencart server

Tags: php, cordova, opencart

I linked my application with one of my OpenCart site. I got data and all other things via AJAX JSONP. Now I am facing a problem to store the order details ,like name address,amount etc to the website server. How I can send data to the controller (`catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php`) with AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new order in OpenCart while observing the POST request sent to the server from the confirm step. By this you should get the idea of what data is being sent and required by OpenCart in order to create an order.

Keep in mind that newly created order is not visible (has no status, it is just some dummy entry in the database) until it is confirmed as well. Confirmation is done by selected payment module (either after confirmation after a credit card or paypal payment or immediately in case of bank transfer for example).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the the answer. Send data to the controller with ajax.Pass it to the models .

Comment: That's what I have suggested in my answer. Maybe you just meant this *answer* as a comment to my answer?